# how to check if controller is already on navigationcontroller viewcontrollers stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

i'm getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported
```

How does one check if a controller already exists in the stack and not push that controller but move to it?

Here's some code where I'm pushing a controller based on a tab selection:

```
func tabSelected(tab: String) {
    switch tab{
    case "payment":
        mainNavigationController.popToViewController(myAccountViewController, animated: true)
    break
    case "delivery":
        mainNavigationController.pushViewController(deliveryViewController, animated: true)
        break
    case "service":
        mainNavigationController.pushViewController(serviceViewController, animated: true)
        break
    case "profile":
        mainNavigationController.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are pushing a same controller to your navigation stack.  You can't push a view controller onto the stack that already exists in the stack. It is probably that you call you `tabSelected()` method multiple times, so you should make sure it doesnt get called multiple times.

A good practice to prevent your crash is to pop off the existing controller, 
which already in the stack. So you should do something like `self.navigationController?.popToViewController(myViewController, animated: true)` whenever you leave your view controller.

Or you can do the following to check whatever your controller is already in the stack:

```
 if (self.navigationController?.topViewController.isKindOfClass(ViewController) != nil) {

}
```

For your particular case, do the following:

```
if(mainNavigationController.topViewController.isKindOfClass(ProfileViewController) != nil) {

    }
```

Comment: So, in ProfileViewController I should self.navigationController?.popToViewController(ProfileViewController, animated: true) when I leave the controller? in viewDidDisappear? viewDidUnload?

Comment: it will probably cause issue if you pop your view controller in `viewDidDisappear`. You usually do `popViewController` when you tap the Cancel or Back button in your navigation bar. If you are building a tab bar basic app with UITabbarController, you should do `tabBarVC.selectedIndex = YOUR_INDEX` to switch between controller. If you are not using UITabbarController, you should implement a UITabbarDelegate, and insert subviews in its delegate method, see [this example](https://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/ios-dev-add-tabbar-to-a-view-without-a-tabbarcontroller/)

Answer (score 4):

You can check the navigation controller's `viewControllers` property.

```
if contains(mainNavigationController.viewControllers, controller) {
  // move it
} else {
  // push it
}
```

Comment: You may need to invert it for more recent versions of Swift: `mainNavigationController.viewControllers.contains { $0 == controller }`.

Answer (score 1):

To check if view controller exists in navigation stack, you can use the following approach. This will compile in Swift 5:

```
    if let stack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
      for vc in stack where vc.isKind(of: SomeViewController.self) {
        debugPrint("exists")
      }
    }
```